# Any reason Origen::Parameter set contexts are hidden from the user?

Tags: origen-sdk

Is there any reason the [Origen::Parameters sets](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/Parameters.html) do not have a public method for retrieving all of the possible set ids?  I do see a public method that works, though it isn't named like it is meant to be used publicly.  Why is this not more visible?

```
[6] pry(#<PPEKit::Product>)> $dut.func._parameter_sets.ids
=> [:default,
 :func_default,
 :func_harvest_default,
```

**EDIT**

@Ginty, I tried your suggestion but it doesn't return the keys I am looking for.  In the first sentence in the [Parameter docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/#Defining_a_Set_of_Parameters), the keys I am looking for are referred to 'parameter contexts'.  The reason these would be useful would be to do something like this:

```
 my_param_key = :my_param_key
 if Origen.top_level.func.has_context? my_param_key
   ...
```

Specifically, I am creating parameter contexts from the information in my flow file and would like to verify that they exist before trying to access them.  Essentially it is a handshake between my test flow and the test method parameters I am storing using unique (hopefully) parameter IDs/contexts.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `dut.func.params` should return a hash-like object which contains all the parameter sets, so to get the IDs is just: `dut.func.params.keys`

**EDIT**

I see now that you want a collection containing the available contexts, but it doesn't seem like that is currently provided via an API.
I don't think there is any particular reason for that, probably hasn't been needed until now.

`params.context` returns the currently active context, I would recommend we add `params.contexts` and/or `params.available_contexts` to return an array of the available context names.

Comment: Hi @Ginty.  I think you misunderstood my intent.  I am not looking for that level of scope.  See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Origen now supports knowing the [available parameter contexts](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/spec/parameters_spec.rb#L288).